# How to set animation on cells in 2048 game?

Tags: java, android, animation, ondraw

i am new to android developing.

I am developing a game called 2048.

Is it possible that cells motion animation done? If yes, how?

its my code:

```
public class GameView extends ImageView {

private Paint paint;
private Paint textPaint;
private int   width;
private int   height;


public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initialize();
}


public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initialize();
}


public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initialize();
}


private void initialize() {
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#aaaaaa"));
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    textPaint = new Paint();
    textPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    textPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    textPaint.setTextSize(G.convertDpToPixel(48));
    textPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
}


@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    if (getWidth() < getHeight()) {
        width = getWidth();
    } else {
        width = getHeight();
    }

}


public void resetGame() {
    G.score = 0;
    G.updateScore();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            G.cells[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    dropNextNumber();
    dropNextNumber();


}


private void dropNextNumber() {
    boolean gameFinished = true;

    int freeCells = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (G.cells[i][j] == 0) {
                freeCells++;
                if (freeCells > 1) {
                    gameFinished = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (gameFinished) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You Lose!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        while (true) {
            int randomX = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
            int randomY = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
            if (G.cells[randomX][randomY] == 0) {
                G.cells[randomX][randomY] = 2;
                break;
            }
        }

        invalidate();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    float size = width / 4.0f;

    float padding = 4;
    float halfSize = size / 2.0f - padding;
    float offset = getWidth() - 4.0f * size;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(getNumberColor(G.cells[i][j])));
            float centerX = (j + 0.5f) * size + offset / 2.0f;
            float centerY = (i + 0.5f) * size;
            RectF rect = new RectF(centerX - halfSize, centerY - halfSize, centerX + halfSize, centerY + halfSize);
            canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, G.convertDpToPixel(8), G.convertDpToPixel(8), paint);
            if (G.cells[i][j] != 0) {
                String textToDraw = new String("" + G.cells[i][j]);
                Rect bounds = new Rect();
                textPaint.getTextBounds(textToDraw, 0, textToDraw.length(), bounds);
                canvas.drawText(textToDraw, centerX, centerY + (bounds.bottom - bounds.top) / 2, textPaint);
            }
        }
    }
}


private void goToUp() {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                int k = i;
                while (k > 0 && G.cells[k - 1][j] == 0) {
                    G.cells[k - 1][j] = G.cells[k][j];
                    G.cells[k][j] = 0;
                    k--;
                }

                if (k > 0) {
                    if (G.cells[k - 1][j] == G.cells[k][j]) {
                        power(k - 1, j);
                        G.cells[k][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    invalidate();
}


public void power(int i, int j) {
    G.cells[i][j] *= 2;
    G.score += G.cells[i][j];
    G.updateScore();
}

 */
private void goToDown() {
    for (int j = 3; j >= 0; j--) {
        for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (i < 3) {
                int k = i;
                while (k < 3 && G.cells[k + 1][j] == 0) {
                    G.cells[k + 1][j] = G.cells[k][j];
                    G.cells[k][j] = 0;
                    k++;
                }

                if (k < 3) {
                    if (G.cells[k + 1][j] == G.cells[k][j]) {
                        power(k + 1, j);
                        G.cells[k][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    invalidate();
}

 */
private void goToLeft() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (j > 0) {
                int k = j;
                while (k > 0 && G.cells[i][k - 1] == 0) {
                    G.cells[i][k - 1] = G.cells[i][k];
                    G.cells[i][k] = 0;
                    k--;
                }

                if (k > 0) {
                    if (G.cells[i][k - 1] == G.cells[i][k]) {
                        power(i, k - 1);
                        G.cells[i][k] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    invalidate();
}


private void goToRight() {
    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 3; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (j < 3) {
                int k = j;
                while (k < 3 && G.cells[i][k + 1] == 0) {
                    G.cells[i][k + 1] = G.cells[i][k];
                    G.cells[i][k] = 0;
                    k++;
                }

                if (k < 3) {
                    if (G.cells[i][k + 1] == G.cells[i][k]) {
                        power(i, k + 1);
                        G.cells[i][k] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    invalidate();
}

private float            lastDownX;
private float            lastDownY;

private boolean          movePending;

private static final int MODE_LEFT  = 1;
private static final int MODE_RIGHT = 2;
private static final int MODE_UP    = 3;
private static final int MODE_DOWN  = 4;


private String getNumberColor(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 0:
            return "#ccc0b3";

        case 2:
            return "#eee4da";

        case 4:
            return "#ede0c8";

        case 8:
            return "#f2b179";

        case 16:
            return "#f59563";

        case 32:
            return "#f67c5f";

        case 64:
            return "#f65e3b";
    }

    return "#ccc0b3";
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            lastDownX = event.getRawX();
            lastDownY = event.getRawY();
            movePending = true;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if ( !movePending) {
                return true;
            }

            int mode = 0;
            float diffX = lastDownX - event.getRawX();
            float diffY = lastDownY - event.getRawY();

            if (Math.abs(diffX) > 10 && Math.abs(diffX) > 2 * Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (diffX > 0) {
                    mode = MODE_LEFT;
                } else {
                    mode = MODE_RIGHT;
                }

                movePending = false;
            }

            if (Math.abs(diffY) > 10 && Math.abs(diffY) > 2 * Math.abs(diffX)) {
                if (diffY > 0) {
                    mode = MODE_UP;
                } else {
                    mode = MODE_DOWN;
                }

                movePending = false;
            }

            switch (mode) {
                case MODE_LEFT:
                    goToLeft();
                    dropNextNumber();
                    break;

                case MODE_RIGHT:
                    goToRight();
                    dropNextNumber();
                    break;

                case MODE_UP:
                    goToUp();
                    dropNextNumber();
                    break;

                case MODE_DOWN:
                    goToDown();
                    dropNextNumber();
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

and [this](http://s4.picofile.com/file/8166004734/device_2014_12_28_005331.gif) my screenshot.

I tried many ways but not any solution.

I appreciate the patience and explain step by step.

i want to set animation like [this](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/3e7c663fa2ef50c4835d0a34b3a7874e806d6c01/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f597133487852792e676966).

Thank you my friends.

Comment: Anyone can not help me?

Comment: No one can help because no one has time to read such a long piece of code. Just include necessary chunks of code to highlight problem.

Comment: What I do to help me?